# export SQLite database from android phone to my system as mdb or accdb database format

Tags: java, android

I want to export SQLite database file created by simple android code. I want to use that database in microsoft access (.mdb or .accdb). Is it possible? If it is possible means, Tell me the steps

**Note**:Here, I didn't put any code.. I just want know what are steps to exporting the sqlite database file to mdb or accdb format file..

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 3):

To get DB from android device

1) just go to `android-sdk-folder/platform-tools`

2) type `adb shell` & press enter

3) `run-as com.yourapp cat /data/data/com.yourapp/databases/FILENAME > /sdcard/FILENAME.db`

& this FILENAME.db you will get in `mnt/sdcard/FILENAME.db`  Location.

After Exporting to the SDCard, Please follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657115/how-to-convert-mdb-to-sqlite-in-android).

Answer (score 0):

You can download database from device.

That does the trick: (Linux/MacOSX)

```
./PATH_TO_ANDROID_SDK/platform-tools/adb -d shell 'run-as PACKAGE /data/data/package/databases/DATABASE_NAME > /sdcard/DATABASE_NAME
```

Then you download from /sdcard/ to computer whole database. (You've got access to write/read perm. in sdcard catalogue)

Script in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

PATHTOSDK="/some_path/"
PACKAGE="com.my.app"
DATABASENAME="mydb.db"
COMMAND=$(${PATHTOSDK}adb -d shell "run-as $PACKAGE cat /data/data/$PACKAGE/databases/$DATABASENAME > /sdcard/$DATABASENAME")
```

In result of this steps you have SQLite DB. Another question is how to port SQLite DB to MS Access DB? Some hints: https://superuser.com/questions/264510/open-sqlite-db-in-microsoft-access