# How to get cookies while browing from the android mobile programmatically?

Tags: android, cookies

I want to get the browser cookies from the android application programmatically.

I got a link for one application (`.apk`) through one customer(i.e. website). The link will redirect me to the server(i.e., the data base of the owner of `.apk` file). Then the owner will check whether the customer is registered. If registered, It'll allow me to download the `.apk` file and the server will also send the Customer Id to the cookies. I want to get the Customer Id from the mobile browser cookies using program.

Comment: are you asking us to provide code ?

Comment: Guide me to get cookies from the mobile browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do some kind of xss. Depending on your website configuration if you set your cookies for all subdomains you could add a new subdomain let's call it xss.example.com where you read the cookies and put them in GET args pointing back to an URL which is caught by your app.

Answer (score 0):

The cookies, for the default android browser, are stored in

`/data/data/com.android.browser/databases/webview.db`.

The problem is that other applications, for security reasons, do not have access to files that do not belong to them, like the database file.

In order for what you are asking to be possible, the Browser application would have to implement this functionality.

Comment: can u send sample code for accessing the cookies

Comment: You can access this Database if your device is rooted?

Comment: refere to get database http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14080985/export-sqlite-database-from-android-phone-to-my-system-as-mdb-or-accdb-database/14081063#14081063